# Brightcove: Go to specific time(s) in video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, brightcove

I am using [Brightcove](https://brightcove.com) for my videos, however, I need to be able to click on a selection of buttons to go to specific timestamps within the video.

I have found how to deep-link (https://support.brightcove.com/deep-linking), but this is to start a video at a specific point, rather than change the time of an existing or playing video.

I need to be let the user click on links like this (as an example):

- Go to 60 seconds
- Go 5 minutes
- Go to 20 minutes

Clicking on any of those links will update the video.

Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't using the deep-linking to start a video at a specific point have the same effect as changing the time of a playing video? On click of the link, just swap out the iFrame code for the iFrame code with the desired timestamp.

Comment: @APAD1, I figured this would be A) more resource-intensive, and B) show a flicker as it reloads the new frame. Changing the current a single video would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [player API](https://support.brightcove.com/overview-player-api)

```
myPlayer.currentTime(60);
```